# When I receive mms gifs, they're stuck on first frame

Tags: huawei, mms

The gifs never play, it only shows the first frame of the gif.

I have a Huawei Sensa LTE that I purchased from Straight Talk.  After speaking with Straight Talk customer service, they have indicated that 'moving pictures' aren't supported on this device, but I refuse to believe this answer.

I have tried several different third party sms/mms apps, and I have tried a lot of suggestions that I found in Google searches. (Disable WiFi+, mess with data settings, try to change APN [phone won't let me, it's locked]).

If I rooted my phone, would I be able to change the APN settings, and could that fix the problem?  Would there be any merit to installing a custom rom or something?

Comment: Try a different texting app, like Textra or Android Messages? I've heard of similar issues with the built-in Huawei SMS app before.

Comment: Yeah, same problem